# Infinitive phrases modifying adjectives

Tags: phrases, adjectives, infinitives

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how these infinitive phrases function (if they are infinitive phrases at all) in the following examples. I have learnt that they can act as nouns, adjectives and adverbs.

Firstly, 
*It was impossible **to understand him**.*
*You were clever **to find the answers so quickly**.*
*You don't look happy **to see me**.*

Then, it occurs to me that what we are modifying are adjectives, and *adverbs* can modify adjectives. In these previous cases, would the phrases be functioning as an adverb?

Secondly,  
*It’s difficult for us **to hear what she’s saying**.*

In this last example, is it acting as a direct object?

> What's difficult? To hear what she's saying.

Or it might be a subject complement.

> To hear what she’s saying is impossible for us.

If so, would it be functioning as a *noun*? 
All the previous examples feature linking verbs as the main verbs.

Finally, in these following sentences, with abstract nouns and indefinite pronouns (and action verbs), it may be easier to see the *adjectival* quality:

*I had no one **to talk to**.* 
*When I’m travelling, I always take something **to read**.*

I would really appreciate any insight about this.  Thank you.

Edit: I have found a [website](https://www.eltconcourse.com/training/inservice/lexicogrammar/adjectives.html#complementation) that explains in detail adjectives. It presents the to-infinitive as a way of complementation. It does not specify whether it's as a noun, and averb or another adjective.

> **Many predicative adjectives can be followed by the to-infinitive.  Examples of the form will suffice here:**
> The hotel was hard to find
> They were thrilled to discover how much
> They are certain to go
> He was quick to respond
> **Again, a few adjectives actually require complementation by a to-infinitive.  For example:**
> The machine is inclined to be noisy
> She is bound to come to your party
> She is able to come

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152029/discussion-on-question-by-fonema-jimena-infinitive-phrases-modifying-adjectives); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.